# populate all array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a schema of `concerts` which I am populating with `reviews` using virtual populate which returns an array of reviews. Now on every review I again have to populate `customerId` to its `name` and `avatar`.

Here is my code

```
const populateReviews = await Concert.findById(id).populate({
    path: "reviews",
    options: {
      sort: { rating: -1, updatedAt: -1 },
    },
  });
const populateCustomers = await Customer.populate(populateReviews, {
  path: "reviews.customerId",
  options: {
    select: { name: 1, avatar: 1 },
  },
});
```

And here is the output of above code.

[image]

I have to populate `customerId`. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating across multiple levels would help you

```
Concert
 .findById(id)
 .populate({
    path: "reviews",
    options: {
      sort: { rating: -1, updatedAt: -1 },
      },
    populate : {
    path : 'customerId',
    options: {
       select: { name: 1, avatar: 1 },
      },
     }
  })
 .exec(function (err, res) {

 })
```

Comment: Yeah, its working thanks bro.

Comment: Yourwelcome,  I'd be thankful if you let me have correct answer